# VBA difference between ShapeRange(1) and ShapeRange.Item(1)

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

Concerned about code falling over in scenarios I haven't thought of during testing and so wanted to understand the difference between these two approaches, which appear to accomplish exactly the same thing:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
```

Context is: Identifying the shape in which the active cursor position is, or if whole shapes selected, the first shape in the selected items (i.e. if there's an active cursor inside a shape, it returns that shape; if the user has selected multiple shapes, it returns the first shape).

Looking at MSDN:

For first option, appears you can add the index in the brackets to access whatever shape number in selected shapes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange

But looking at "Item", appears to do exactly the same thing by definition "Returns a single Shape object from the specified ShapeRange collection."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange.item

What is the difference and in what situations can it lead to erroring out?

TIA

Comment: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/vba-trap-default-members/

Comment: Thanks for that Tim - really helpful reading. Nice to learn a new fundamental!

Answer (score 2):

That link posted by Tim Williams gives a good explanation of what's going on - well worth a read.

In answer to your specific questions:

1. There's no difference in the two lines of code. Since `.Item` is the default property of a collection object, `ShapeRange(1)` is doing the same as `ShapeRange.Item(1)`. Coding style is a matter of personal preference, but most VBA developers avoid implicit references. Having said that, I'd say most of us do leave out `.Item` when referencing a collection, eg `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. If you're interested, I do find `.Item` useful for code that is wrapped in a `With ... End With` block:

   ```
   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       .Add After:=.Item(.Count)
   End With
   ```
2. No, your code won't fail. The only reason it might fail would be if Microsoft changed its default property for the Collection object, and you're more likely to be eaten by a shark while being struck by lightening on the same day your lottery numbers came up.

Comment: Thank you so much Ambie!